# Core Data - Fetch doesn't deliver the same result

Tags: ios, core-data

So I'm adding a ListItem into ListName(There is a one to many relationship setted up) in a Class A

[image: relationship]

```
ListItem *newItem = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ListItem"
inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
//setting some attributes...

[listName addListItemsObject:newItem];
[self.context save:&error];
```

After that Class B is via a delegate methode called

There I want to get the data out of Core Data, BUT...If I'm fetching all ListName, the ListItems are not up to date(for example only 5 items instead of 6). If I fetch all ListItems then there are all there(6 out of 6).

What is wrong with my code...I need to get all ListNames though

```
NSError *error;
NSFetchRequest *req = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
if(context == nil)
   NSLog(@"context is nil");

NSEntityDescription *descr = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ListName" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
[req setEntity:descr];

NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"lastModified" ascending:NO];

[req setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

NSArray * results = [self.context executeFetchRequest:req error:&error];

self.listNames = [results mutableCopy];
if ([results count] > 0) {
    ListName *test = [results objectAtIndex:0];
    [test.listItems count];
    NSLog(@"item count on list %i", [test.listItems count]);
    //wrong result

    NSFetchRequest *newReq = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *descr = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ListItem" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
    [newReq setEntity:descr];

    NSArray * results2 = [self.context executeFetchRequest:newReq error:&error];
    NSLog(@"item count on items %i", [results2 count]);
    //right result

}
```

Comment: If I'm fetching over listname, the count of the listitems is 5 instead of 6. If I'm fetching over ListItems then it's 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple [reset](http://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/reset) has helped

Comment: Don't use reset as a generic context reset. It's intended for use with he undo manager.

Answer (score 0):

Given your data model and code, there is no reason that the count of ListItems in both places as to be the same because the counts are of two different sets of objects that do not necessarily overlap.

The first count is given by this code:

```
ListName *test = [results objectAtIndex:0];
[test.listItems count];
```

… which returns the count of `ListItems` objects in the relationship of a single, particular and unique `ListName` object. You may have one `ListName` object or you might have hundreds each of which could have an arbitrary number of related `ListItems` objects. This code will only count those related to he first `ListName` object returned.

The second count is given by:

```
NSFetchRequest *newReq = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *descr = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ListItem" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
[newReq setEntity:descr];

NSArray * results2 = [self.context executeFetchRequest:newReq error:&error];
NSLog(@"item count on items %i", [results2 count]);
```

… which returns an unfiltered array containing every instance of `ListItems` in the persistent store regardless of what relationships they have.

There is no particular reason to expect the first count to ever agree with the second because it will only do so when (1) you have a single `ListNames` object in the store and (2) every existing `ListItems` object is in that `ListNames.listNames` relationship.

Make sure not confuse entities and managed objects.

BTW, you should almost always use reciprocal relationships e.g. if you have `ListNames.listItems` you should have a reciprocal `ListItems.listName`.